# ivars naming conventions and @synthesis

Tags: objective-c

Sorry for the long read. This is a part of the book I'm confused on.

> The current trend in coding conventions (which Xcode 4 has adopted) is
>   to use an underscore (_) as the leading character for an instance
>   variable name. So any references you see in the template code
>   generated by Xcode to variables starting with a _ are referencing the
>   instance variables directly by name. When you see an @synthesize
>   directive that looks like this
>
> @synthesize window=_window;

Why couldn't `_window` be declared in @propterty/synthesize in the first place instead of assigning it to `window`?

> it says to synthesize the getter and setter for the property named
>   window and to associate that property with an instance variable called
>   _window (which does not have to be explicitly declared). This helps to distinguish the use of the instance variable from the property and to
>   encourage you to set and retrieve the value of the instance variable
>   through the setter and getter methods. That is, writing something like
>   this
>
> [window makeKeyAndVisible]; // This won't work
>
> will fail, as there is no instance variable named window. Instead, you
>   have to either name the instance variable directly by its name, such
>   as
>
> [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
>
> or, preferably, use the accessor method:
>
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Why does `self.window` not need the underscore when the other methods do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only access the underscore ivars within the setter/getter methods. In this case it would be within the implementations of `- (UIWindow *)window` and `- (void)setWindow:(UIWindow *)window`. Anywhere else in your class's implementation, refer to the `@property` and not the synthesized ivar (`self.window`). One thing that helped me understand in my early obj-c days was this: `self.window = ...;` is synonymous to `[self setWindow:...];` Just follow the rules and you'll be one happy

Apple's internal implementation of Objective-C results in some extremely nifty memory management that you will never have to deal with as long as you abide by their rules. Typical Apple, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `self.window` is actually invoking a method (though it may not seem to).  For instance if you `@synthesize` a `@property` named `window` *or* you define a method like `- (id) window { ... }` yourself, `self.window` will call that method and represent whatever value was returned.  Similarly, `self.window = value;` implicitly calls `[self setWindow:value]` for you.

A `@property` can rename these default methods, e.g. using `getter=`.